# KafkaError{code=_UNKNOWN_TOPIC,val=-188,str="Unable to produce message: Local: Unknown topic"} error while using kafka producer in Python

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, confluent-kafka-python

I am using python script for kafka producer and getting the following error:

```
cimpl.KafkaException: KafkaError{code=\_UNKNOWN_TOPIC,val=-188,str="Unable to produce message: Local: Unknown topic"}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
cimpl.KafkaException: KafkaError{code=_UNKNOWN_TOPIC,val=-188,str="Unable to produce message: Local: Unknown topic"}
%4|1668330504.791|TERMINATE|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:app]: Producer terminating with 320 messages (1006004 bytes) still in queue or transit: use flush() to wait for outstanding message delivery
```

Comment: What is unclear from the exception and what debugging steps have you done? For example, try actually creating the topic you want to produce to, first?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the topic you are producing to does not exist. You can create a topic using the create [command](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/clients/confluent-kafka-python/html/index.html#confluent_kafka.admin.AdminClient.create_topics). Read more [here](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/clients/confluent-kafka-python/html/index.html#confluent_kafka.admin.AdminClient.create_topics)